# Parameter for CoreAudio Converter NewTimePitch

Tags: ios, core-audio

According to documentation, there are kTimePitchParam_Rate and kTimePitchParam_Pitch to control. But I don't know if they are float or int, and what are there max and min

[Audio Unit Parameters REF](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioUnitParametersReference/Reference/reference.html)

Anybody know what values should I pass in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corect paramaters are:

> ```
> // Parameters for AUNewTimePitch
> enum {
>       // Global, rate, 1/32 -> 32.0, 1.0
>   kNewTimePitchParam_Rate                         = 0,
>       // Global, Cents, -2400 -> 2400, 1.0
>   kNewTimePitchParam_Pitch                        = 1,
>       // Global, generic, 3.0 -> 32.0, 8.0
>   kNewTimePitchParam_Overlap                      = 4,
>       // Global, Boolean, 0->1, 1
>   kNewTimePitchParam_EnablePeakLocking            = 6
> };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From the page you linked:

> All parameter values are of the same data type: 32-bit floating point

For more information on `kTimePitchParam_Rate` see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1717/_index.html:

> The kTimePitchParam_Rate parameter declared in AudioUnitParameters.h
>   is used to control audio playback rate from 0.5x to 2.0x speed.
>   AudioUnitParameterValue is a Float32 rounded by the unit to whichever
>   of the following is closest: 0.5, 0.66667, 0.8, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 2. A
>   playback rate of 1.0 is the default.